# homomorphism $\phi$ : $\mathbb Z$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb Z$ using $\phi(n)$=$2n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A question from Visual group theory says :

consider the homomorphism $\phi$ : $\mathbb Z$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb Z$ by $\phi(n)$=$2n$,where the group operation on $\mathbb Z$ is '+'.
Would $\phi$ be an homomorphism if it were to use a different coeffiecient than 2?

I think it should remain so for any coeffiecient because it does not violate the properties for homomorphism. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Yes. That it is a homomorphism is called the "distributive property of multiplication over addition". ;-)

Comment: Well, "does not violate" requires proof. On a language note, I'd say,  "... because it satisfies the properties for homomorphism." The phrase: "... does not violate" is implicitly a double negative, and, if you were to prove it is a homomorphism, you'd just prove that it satisfies the condition directly.

Comment: $2(n_1+n_2) = 2 n_1 + 2 n_2$.

Comment: While it's somewhat implicit in the question, it would be better to write $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ here to make it explicit that (a) this is a group homomorphism and not e.g. a mapping with respect to some larger structure such as a ring;and (b) that it's the usual group operation on $\mathbb{Z}$ and not something a bit more exotic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group ${\mathbb Z}$ is cyclic, so it suffices to define a homomorphism to another group by giving the image of its generator; we have two generators to choose from, $\pm 1$, so it's perfectly all right to define $\phi$ by giving $\phi(1)$.

${\mathbb Z}$ is free abelian, so any $\phi(1)$ is good.  On the other hand, if you consider ${\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}$, here the generator must satisfy $n\phi(\overline{1})=0$ for any group homomorphism
$$\phi:{\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}\to G.$$

---

In the case where $G={\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z},$ the condition that $\phi(\overline{1})$ must satisfy due to the source group adds to the condition the target group satisfies, i.e.

$$\phi(\overline{1})\in {\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z} \mbox{ and so } m\phi(\overline{1})=0.$$

This is best expressed by the well-known relation 
$$Hom({\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}, {\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z})={\mathbb Z}/d{\mathbb Z},$$
where $(m,n)=d$.

If $dm_1=m$, then $\phi(1)$ need be a multiple of $m_1$ in ${\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z}$, so both relations satisfy.

---

By the above, one always has the relation (in principle, as sets)
$$Hom({\mathbb Z},G)=G$$ given by $\phi \mapsto \phi(1).$  However, the l.h.s. has a group structure only if $G$ is abelian, in general.  If $G$ is abelian, then the above bijection is a group homomorphism.

Comment: Just because a homomorphism $\phi$:$G$ $\rightarrow$ $H$ is determined by the image of its generators does not mean that any such image will work.$e.g$: suppose we try to define homomorphism $\phi$:$\mathbb Z3$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb Z4$ by $\phi(1)=1$ , then we get $\phi(0)=\phi(1+1+1)=3$ which isn't possible as $\phi(0)=0$.does $\mathbb Z$ being cyclic ensure that just mapping its generators will make the  homomorphism.

Comment: I can't understand that how you assumed "define ϕ by giving ϕ(1).".please explain.

Comment: your explanation would be helpful for me in accepting answer.I already upvoted for the answer.

Comment: I added the corresponding paragraph.  In reality, since ${\mathbb Z}$ is a free group, describing the image of its generator $1$ (or $-1$ depending on your taste) fixes the homomorphism, namely if $\phi(1)=g$ and $n$ is a natural number, $\phi(n)=g^n.$  Likewise, if $n=-m$ is a negative integer, then $\phi(-m)=g^{-m}.$  This does not happen if the source is a finite cyclic group, see my answer, simply because there is a relation to be satisfied in the source group and another one in the target.

Comment: I've just added another paragraph, in which framework you will see another answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sure! If you just left $\phi(n)=kn$ then you can show that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that the homomorphism properties hold.

Comment: Even for $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Even for $k\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\phi:(G,\ast)\to (G',\star)$ is an homomorphism for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, you just need to prove that for all $a,b \in G$:

$$\phi(a \ast b)=\phi(a) \star \phi(b)$$ 
So in the case of the endomorphism $\phi:(\mathbb{Z},+) \to (\mathbb{Z},+)$ with $\phi(n)=kn, k\in\mathbb{Z}$, this means that:
$$k(a+b)=ka+kb$$